# How to write a simple animation code using Fortran OpenGl?

Tags: opengl, animation, fortran

I am trying to write a simple code in Fortran OpenGl to animate the dynamics of a linear polymer.On a square lattice, initially a straight linear polymer is a horizontal sequence of successive top-left and top-right bonds. Equivalently, this is a series of up and down kinks. The biased dynamics is a sequence of moves of down ->> up kinks, the down kinks are selected at random and with uniform probabilities. To animate this I need to erase two bonds of the down kink and then draw two bonds of the up kink. The "erasing" a bond is executed by "drawing" another bond on top of it using the background colour. The problem is when I run my code for a certain duration of Monte Carlo time, it is giving me the correct picture of the final configuration of the polymer at the end of the simulation, but not showing the sequence of intermediate microscopic moves of kink flipping. I guess, I must be missing one or more graphic commands. I can send the code if anybody tries to help. Finally, I am working in the Linux (Ubuntu) environment. Thanks a lot in advance.

Part of the code:

!----FOR ERASING A DOWN KINK

```
  call glColor3f(1.0,1.0,0.0)     ! Back ground colour: Yellow
  call drawline((i-1)*f,s(im1,j)*f,i*f,s(i,j)*f)
  call drawline(i*f,s(i,j)*f,(i+1)*f,s(ip1,j)*f)

  s(i,j)=s(i,j)+2
```

!----FOR DRAWING AN UP KINK

```
  call glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0)     ! Polymer colour: Red
  if(i.ne.1)call drawline((i-1)*f,s(im1,j)*f,i*f,s(i,j)*f)
  if(i.ne.Lx)call drawline(i*f,s(i,j)*f,(i+1)*f,s(ip1,j)*f)
```

Comment: Which Fortran version?

Comment: I used a code in fortran 90

Comment: Fine. Take a look at the examples in the packages http://math.nist.gov/f90gl/software.html of **[f90gl](http://math.nist.gov/f90gl/)**.

Comment: What about drawing to a second (empty) buffer from scratch and swapping buffers when you are finished? I did such things with [f03gl](http://www-stone.ch.cam.ac.uk/pub/f03gl/) in the past and was really satisfied with the results.